# PHP: How To Use Snappy (wkhtmltopdf wrapper)

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf using Snappy. I've already read the documentation at https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy and try the code.

```
require_once '/KnpLabs/src/autoload.php';

use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

$snappy = new Pdf('C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf');

// Display the resulting image in the browser
// by setting the Content-type header to jpg
$snappy = new Pdf('C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://localhost/pdfTester/try.php');
```

when i click a link on try.php, there is a popup to open the pdf file and when i choose to open, a message appears.

> Adobe Reader could not open 'file.pdf' because it is either not
> supported file type or because the file has been damaged

btw i just got one month-old exp with php and i already search for same topic but it looks like cannot help much. Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- Your path `C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf` looks like it's pointing to a folder rather than the binary. If your wkhtmltopdf is installed into the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\` the binary would probably be `C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe`, maby try pointing to the executable to see if that works?
- If that doesn't work, what happens when you try to run the command from command line? Does it work then?

  `wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/pdfTester/try.php test.pdf`

Comment: already did the binary one but still cannot solve..and the 2nd way, it works in command line @Nenotlep

Comment: problem solved..the path should be like `C://"Program Files (x86)"/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.exe`

Comment: Good! The example path on their site points to a binary too, but it just looks like a folder so where it says `new Pdf('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf')` the `/usr/local/bin` is the folder and `wkhtmltopdf` is the executable binary. I think they should add a windows example too just to be clear on issues like this.

Comment: @Nenotlep, I tried the code of OP with the suggested answer with the last line of code being `echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.github.com');` and I get the same error that the post mentioned.  This link ( https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/44) also discusses the problem with no answer provided finally. Any way ?

Comment: @Nenotlep, in the path address why should there be `(x86)` as this is not there in Windows 7 ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I don't really know about your situation, but that x86 comes from the automatic install path. There are often two Program Files folders, one for 64bit programs and one for 32bit programs and x86 is for 32bit. I personally like installing wkhtmltopdf in `c:\wkhtmltopdf\`, because that path is easy to write and remember. Maybe you could try that too? The path should point to wherever you have wkhtmltopdf installed :).